# Foreach loop issues in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is some code I have: (p just echos plus adds a newline)

```
foreach ($vanSteps as $k => $reqInfo) 
{
    p($k);
    if ('van' == $k) { p('The key is the van, continue'); continue; }//continue if we reached the part of the array where van is key
    //do stuff
}
```

and I'm getting this output:

```
0
The key is the van, continue
1
2
3
van
The key is the van, continue
```

Why does the if statement return true when the key is 0? This foreach loop handles logic that applies when the key == 0 (and any other key except if the key is 'van') and this messes up the logic because it's return true when key is 0.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, can we see a print_r on `$vanSteps`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `===` for this comparison. When PHP compares string and integer it first casts string to integer value and then does comparison.

See [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in manual.

Comment: ...and 'van' == 0, but 'van' !== 0

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'll be sure to look for this when debugging in the future. =]

Comment: That's a popular mistake, and often overlooked in various PHP tutorials.

Comment: It's certainly not a popular mistake, common perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP `'van' == 0` is `true`.  This is because when using `==` to compare a string and a number, the string is converted to a number (as described in the second link below); this makes the comparison internally become `0 == 0` which is of course `true`.

The suggested alternative for your needs, would be to use a strict equality comparison using `===`.

See [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/==) and [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, when you compare 2 types, it has to convert them to the same type. In your case, you compare `string` with `int`.
Internally this gets converted to

`if((int)'van'==0)....`
and then 
`if((int)'van'==1)....`

(int)'any possible string' will be `0`:) So you either have to manually convert the both values to the same type, or use `===` as a comparison operator, instead of the loose `=`.
An exception from this rule(as pointed out in the comments) would be if the string start with a number, or can be interpreted as a number in any way(1, 0002, -1 etc). In this case, the string would be interpreted as a number, diregarding the end of the non-numeric end-of-string

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for more details.

Comment: Should be *"(int)'any possible string not starting with digits' will be `0`"* ;)

Comment: @Felix - The string can start with a non-digit character and still be interpreted as something other than zero.

Comment: @salathe: Do you mean the sign? I actually just wanted to point out that not *every* strings is converted to zero...

Comment: @Felix, yes. Next time say what you mean. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
$array = array(0=>"a",1=>"b","van"=>"booya!");

function p($v){ echo "{$v}<br />"; }

foreach ($array as $k => $reqInfo) 
{
    p($k);
    if ('van' === $k) { p('The key is the van, continue'); continue; }//continue if we reached the part of the array where van is key
    //do stuff
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
van
The key is the van, continue
```

Note the `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Comparison with Various Types table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
When one of the operand is number, the other operand is converted to number too. Since 'van' is non-numeric sting, it's converted to 0. You should use === operator in the case, which also checks the variable type

Answer (score 0):

Its interpreting the `'van'` as a boolean value (`false`) which 0 is equal to.

To check for exact matches in type and value in PHP you must use `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

That's becuase `'van' == 0` (true).

Instead, you should use `'van' === 0` (false).

In short, use === instead of ==.