# PHP equality seems obviously wrong in foreach loop

Tags: php

For this code:

```
<?php

$data = array('0' => 'A_VALUE');

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "Something to match the key on") {
    print_r($key);
    print_r('key matches');
  }
}
```

I get this output

> 0key matches

Online example here: http://3v4l.org/dKOWq#v431

I cannot for the life of me work out why I am getting this. The comparison should clearly return FALSE.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Use `===` and you are good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string

Comment: +1 to @davidkonrad. It's generally best to use `===` in preference to `==`; you'll save yourself a lot of this type of issue.

Comment: btw, the same applies in Javascript, and other loose-typed languages.

Comment: +1 to @Bora. Yet another question to spawn a dozen answers.

Comment: @bora - it is not a duplicate. This is because the foreach loop is casting the '0' to an int. That is an extra issue not in the other qusetion.

Comment: This is a good question. If it is a duplicate, close it as such. It does not deserve down votes.

Comment: It doesnt matter. Try with `key($data)`, you'll get same result. This issue about wrong comparison and you can find the answer searching on SO and I can find dozen answers for you about your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205238/foreach-loop-issues-in-php etc..

Comment: @bora - I am not claiming it is not a duplicate. I just think the duplicate it is linked to doesn't contain the full answer. The implicit casting of the key is a crucial ingredient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can someone explain this to me?

[Type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Since you are using `==`, PHP compares a `0` (int) to `Something to match the key on` (string). Both sides are cast to an `int`. So `Something to match the key on` become `0`. And `0 == 0` is `true`.

Use [strict equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) or explicit casting.

For example:

```
if ((string)$key == (string)"Something to match the key on") {
  // code
}
```

Comment: This is correct. The subtlety I was missing was that the foreach loop is silently converting the '0' to an int. Could you please add that detail to your answer so that SO has the complete answer (note this detail makes it a different question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

Comment: Indeed, type juggling is one of those *helpful* things in PHP. But sometimes it can be *too* helpful. I make it a habit to use strict equality using explicit casting if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use === to check for type AND value equality, to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, check the [type comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) tables. This page explains how PHP computes every possible type of comparisons.

Comment: + for the link to the docs. Although this is more a comment.

Comment: True enough, I hesitated to post it as a comment to your answer, but thought it could be seen as an answer to this type of question aswell.

Answer (score 0):

**"===" is used for check with "Datatype"**

used this code for compare

```
<?php

$data = array('0' => 'A_VALUE');

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if ($key === "Something to match the key on") {
    print_r($key);
    print_r('key matches');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use === for equality this always gives you the correct result.